# Appending a bunch of check box inputs to a form before submission and then hiding them

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a form I'm building, I'm using a jQuery UI dialog to give the user a list of about 50 check box options. The text boxes get removed from the form completely when they're added to a dialog, so I have to clone and reinsert them to the form before submission so that all of the check box values will be submitted along with the form. The problem is that the checkboxes, when added back into the form, appear visibly. I'm just trying to make them invisible and still be able to submit the values.

I thought maybe doing something like prepend() might be a solution so that the user doesn't actually see the checkboxes, being all the way at the bottom of the form--but it still pushes the form elements down. So I'm looking for a means of appending the `#states_container :input` to the form without it visibly affecting the form in any way.

Code:

```
    $('#submit_btn').click(function(e){

        $("#form_submission").validate({});

        if ($("#form_submission").valid()) {
            $("#form_submission").append($('#states_container :input').clone());
            $("form#form_submission").submit();
       } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Please make sure all required information has been provided before submission.")
       }

   });
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want there to be a space for the checkboxes before they appear or are you afraid that the checkboxes push the form past the end of the page? Or are you trying to collect all the checkbox input values before making them disappear from the page?

Comment: The text boxes get removed from the form completely when they're added to a dialog, so I have to reinsert them to the form before submission so that all of the check box values will be submitted along with the form. The problem is that the checkboxes, when added back into the form, appear visibly. I'm just trying to make them invisible and still be able to submit the values.

Comment: You can `.serialize()` the form before removing any of the input elements without losing their values.

Comment: If you're just trying to have invisible checkboxes, why can't you add their values to an `<input type="hidden"/>`?

Comment: I am also not quite sure what you want to achieve. But I might agree with mavrosxristoforos. A hidden input probably will work for you. Tim, can you please edit your post to give us more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `div` at the bottom of your form. Style it's display to none and give it a unique id.

```
<div id="checkBoxes" style="display:none;"></div>
```

When you go to clone the check boxes from your jQuery dialog set their location to:

```
document.getElementById("checkBoxes").innerHTML = varWithCheckBoxes;
```

This will place all of your check boxes inside an invisible div that will have no affect on your layout and will still be submitted along with your form. In addition if the need arises to repopulate that list of check boxes to make changes you can simply grab them from the div and place them back in the dialog box.